# I'm trying to print the first and last name using object destructuring in javascript but it gives an error for the forEaach function

Tags: javascript

Here's my code :

```
const person = {
        first: 'abc',
        last: 'xyz',
        twitter: '@abcxyz',
        company: 'company name'
    }


const displayName = arr => {
    arr.forEach(item => {
        console.log(`i ${item.first} ${item.last}`)
    })
}

displayName(person)
```

It gives me the arr.forEach is not a function error.

Comment: You are calling `forEach` on the `person` object, which is not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing a couple of things here.

First, you are invoking the `forEach` method on a plain object. It is only defined on arrays. So you can make your code work by making your person object an array of people. Like this:

```js
const person = [{
  first: 'abc',
  last: 'xyz',
  twitter: '@abcxyz',
  company: 'company name'
}];

const displayName = arr => {
  arr.forEach(item => {
    console.log(`i ${item.first} ${item.last}`)
  })
}

displayName(person)
```

Second, your question title speaks of object destructuring. Your code is not actually doing destructuring. To really do destructuring, you want this:

```js
const person = [{
  first: 'abc',
  last: 'xyz',
  twitter: '@abcxyz',
  company: 'company name'
}];

const displayName = arr => {
  arr.forEach(({first, last}) => {
    console.log(`i ${first} ${last}`)
  })
}

displayName(person)
```

"Destructuring" means that the left side of the arrow, or in general, the parameter section of a function, is a *pattern*, rather than a simple sequence of variables. When the function is called, the arguments are matched into the pattern.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's more simple:

```js
const person = {
        first: 'abc',
        last: 'xyz',
        twitter: '@abcxyz',
        company: 'company name'
    }

const displayName = ({first, last}) => console.log(`i ${first} ${last}`)

displayName(person)
```